# How to increment the value of index number each time when the loop is executed in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I have a table column in which there are 'n' number of combo-boxes, When I click on a combo-box, drop down list has to be displayed.

I have repeat above validation for 'n' number of combo-boxes in that column. So I have used loop.

I have shared the code below, In the below code how to increment the index value of **get()** method every time when the loop is executed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
element.all(by.css("all combo boxes")).each(function(combobox) {
    combobox.click().then(function() {
        waitForElement(element.all(by.css("dropdownlist").get(0));
        combobox.click();
    })
})
```

Comment: I think you make the question confused.  I guess there is a combo-box at each row. After you click on comb-box, it should display N options. You need to verify each combo-box have N options. It's right?

Comment: @yong Yes, You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly you could try declaring the counter outside the loop as follows:

**Updated:**

```
let i = 0;
element.all(by.css("all combo boxes")).each(function(combobox) {
    combobox.click().then(function() {
        waitForElement(element.all(by.css("dropdownlist").get(i));
        combobox.click();

        //moved inside of then
        i++;
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm getting a timeout error upon incrementing the index value through variable "i". But there are no timeout error(Failed: Wait timed out after 60003ms) when I'm hard coding the index value.

Comment: @Poovin I've changed my solution to move the incremenation (thought that was a word..) inside the .then block, could you try it once again?

Comment: I confused above code. As the code showed,  for first comb-box, i=0,  second comb-box, i=1,  thrid comb-box, i=2.  The code does not verify every comb-box has same amount options.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
const comboBoxes = element.all(by.css('all combo boxes'));
const dropdownlist = element.all(by.css('dropdownlist'));

for(let i =0;i<await comboBoxes.count();i++){
await combobox.get(i).click();
await  browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(await dropdownlist.get(i)),30000,'The wait for element to be visible');
await combobox.get(i).click();
}
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the ideal solution, but if you are trying to always get the first item from the list, you could just use `.first()` instead of `.get(index)`